# How to install patterns and packages at the same time?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

How can I install package patterns (e.g. "C/C++ development tools") and packages (e.g. "mercurial") at the same time? Currently, two commands are necessary; for example, the installation instructions I wrote for `sketch-frontend` are,

```
sudo zypper install -t pattern "devel_C_C++" "devel_java"
sudo zypper install java-1_6_0-openjdk-devel mercurial
```

[ [link](https://bitbucket.org/gatoatigrado/sketch-frontend/wiki/Installation#!dependencies-linux-opensuse-ubuntu-fedora-debian-mandrivia) ].

*(motivation)*. It's true one only needs two commands, but on machines with slower internet connections (or slower processors), not having the second command automatically continue is annoying. Also, the user *does* need to be prompted for package resolution, so just adding the `--non-interactive` flag is not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

edit: appending `<resolveabletype>:` to the resolvable allows you to match different types in one command it seems.

> zypper in java-1_6_0-openjdk-devel mercurial +pattern:devel_C_C++
>   +pattern:devel_java

---

creating a one-click install will let you do package resolution in one go, but i am unsure if a pattern can be called from within one. http://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:One_Click_Install_ISV#Create_a_web_install_link you could then call it with oci `/sbin/OCICLI /path/to/foobar.ymp`

Comment: Looks good.  Had to look up the syntax of `zypper` to see that in this case `sh` means `zypper shell` and `in` means `zypper install`.

Comment: the answer wasn't documented in zypper's man page for some weird reason.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution:

```
sudo zypper install -t pattern "devel_C_C++" "devel_java" && sudo zypper install java-1_6_0-openjdk-devel mercurial
```

If you're worried that `sudo` will time out after 5 minutes and you don't want the user to have to type their password twice, you could do

```
sudo sh -c 'zypper install -t pattern "devel_C_C++" "devel_java" && zypper install java-1_6_0-openjdk-devel mercurial'
```

---

UPDATE

Since it sounds like you wanted it all to be a single call to `zypper install`, a few more ideas:

1. run `zypper search` or `zypper list` twice, parse the package names, combine the output, and run `zipper install` once with a full list of packages
2. run `zypper install --dry-run` to print the output, then ask the user to confirm, then run `zypper install` without the dry-run option if the user answers yes
3. run `zypper install --download-only` twice with a custom packages dir, then run `zypper install <that directory>/*.rpm` (see `mktemp -d` and the `packagesdir` option in [`zypp.conf`](http://doc.opensuse.org/projects/libzypp/12.1/group__ZyppConfig.html)

Comment: The idea was to have `zypper` prompt for resolutions all in one go. The problem with your solution is that after the first command will finish, it will hang waiting for user input. (which, supposing the user has switched tasks since downloading may take time, is bad.)

Comment: Is it possible to parse the output of the `info` or `search` subcommands?  Or use the `--dry-run` option to print what would happen, then ask the user to press `Y` or `N`, and then re-run the same command without the `--dry-run` option?

Comment: It's not just "yes or no", in some cases the user needs to select a resolution option (Zypper prints out 3 choices, e.g. "do not install X", "downgrade Y", "uninstall Z"). Don't spend too much time on it if `llua`'s answer works (I'll test it soon), thanks anyway!

Comment: #3 looks like it'll would work and will get package solution in one run, but it would be two commands again. @gatoatigrado i don't think you will be able to get this in 'one command' & 'one package resolution' _without_ more work on your end. ie one-click install.

Comment: but it is always possible just list whats in each pattern and add the packages to one huge `zypper install ...`